# Today Extension in iOS app with ionic framework

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, today-extension

I am developing one app in ionic framework and its working as expected and now I want to add Today extension in my iOS app and for that I found some links from where I am able to add Today extension in my app.

Link : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-build-a-today-widget-app-extension-with-ionic/84960/4

This link helps me and I have successfully added Today extension in my app but some time while build my app it will removed my Today extension Target from my app and my whole code removed.

Any idea to add Today extension through ionic framework so while I build my app it will not remove that extension ?

I haven't tried [this](https://github.com/DavidStrausz/cordova-plugin-today-widget) plugin any comment on this plugin should I use this for my Today extension ?

Comment: if you want to implement "Today" extension in ionic then you must have to use plugin because every time you prepare/run app through command line then all the code which you have write in native(xcode) will be removed. So instead of native use existing plugin or create new plugin.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati can you please guide me on this how can I write plugin for extension as I am unable to find Today extension plugin.

Comment: Sorry but i too haven't idea for plugin for extension.i will check and will try to help you on this.